# Mix numbers of columns in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to control the number of columns on a page-by-page basis?

It seems that he number of columns is a global setting and the only strategy that I've come up with for getting around it is to create a table 1 cell high by the number of columns I want wide and hide the borders.

Any suggestions for a less kludgy approach?

Answer (score 2):

Strictly it's not available in page-by-page basis, but it's available on a selected_text-by-selected_text basis.

Select the text to apply the column settings.
Apply the column settings, let say two columns

Select another text to apply the column settings.
Apply the column settings, let say three columns.

Reference

- [Add of delete columns in a document](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7029052?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check the snapshot I've attached. I am using one, two and three columns on the same page.

What you need to do is to select your target texts, then go to "Format" ,then "Columns".

Basically, you should switch the idea of page-based to text-based. You even do not need column break, which hides in the "Break" section.

Answer (score -2):

I found a way to do this in Google Docs. Use a table with the maximum number of columns you might want. Then for the rows, in which you don't want that many columns, select the columns and merge them. This will result in a mixed number of columns for different rows.